# QWebView: how to load web page without images?

Tags: qt, qwebview

How to prevent QWebView from loading images (for traffic saving reasons)?

Comment: You can't do it just using QWebView becuase it download whole site and then just display what you want. If you need to skip images, you have to do it another way

Comment: @Blood: is there any easy way to do it? In fact, I don't need QWebView itself, I don't need to display the page and I'm working with QWebPage that I get from my QWebView. I only use web view for downloading the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be disabled in QWebView's settings:

```
web_view = QWebView()
web_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
```